# How to play a PCM stream (over UDP) in a javascript web client?

Tags: javascript, audio, client, streaming, rtp

I am writing a javascript web client, and I want to play audio that encoded as PCM from a UDP stream (raw RTP) in my client (I can change the destination host and port of the stream freely). How can it be done?

I read about Howler and I couldn't find any UDP listening option or PCM support. I also looked about WebRTC but it doesn't seem to support PCM (if I got it correctly).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ScottStensland So if I get it right, you suggest writing kind of a proxy between the the server that streams the UDP and my client?

Comment: I wrote my own nodejs server to stream PCM to a web audio api browser client yet its not for public consumption ...  I see https://github.com/binaryjs/binaryjs  should give you a server side solution ...  I must say its a fun project to roll your own server although getting the web audio api client to be hickup free was more of a challenge

Comment: as I had to include web workers on the browser side to handle the server initiated interrupts  such that browser client audio rendering event loop was never interrupted ... infact the audio event loop owned the job of plucking queued up buffers which got populated by web worker ...  this was several years ago hopefully web audio api has been beefed up since - dunno

Comment: https://github.com/scottstensland/websockets-streaming-audio    was working fine when I published it years ago ... looks like it needs some attention to get it back in the saddle again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally did it!
I wrote a little python server to convert the UDP to a websocket.
I wrote it using Quart, whuch is like a async flask in order to make the websocket and the UDP selecting easier:

```
import json
import struct
import socket
import asyncio
from quart import Quart, websocket

app = Quart(__name__)


class PcmServerProtocol:
    def __init__(self, queue: asyncio.Queue):
        self._queue = queue

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport

    def datagram_received(self, data, addr):
        pcm_chunks = struct.unpack(
            # Convert the data to pulses
            "<" + "h" * (len(data) // struct.calcsize("h")),
            data
        )
        self._queue.put_nowait(json.dumps(pcm_chunks))


async def sending(queue: asyncio.Queue):
    while True:
        data = await queue.get()
        await websocket.send(data)


@app.websocket("/sound")
async def sound():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 15000))
    pcm_queue = asyncio.Queue()
    streamer = asyncio.create_task(sending(pcm_queue))
    pcm_receiver = asyncio.create_task(
        asyncio.get_event_loop().create_datagram_endpoint(
            lambda: PcmServerProtocol(pcm_queue), sock=sock
        )
    )
    await asyncio.gather(streamer, pcm_receiver)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Now all we need is to connect with a web socket and play the sound from the javascript
and for that I used Web Audio API:

```
let audioCtx = new AudioContext();
let ws = new WebSocket('ws://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/sound');
ws.onmessage = function (event) {
    let pcm_chunks = JSON.parse(event.data);
    let node = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
    let buffer = audioCtx.createBuffer(1, pcm_chunks.length, 44100);
    let data = buffer.getChannelData(0);
    for (let i = 0; i < pcm_chunks.length; i++) {
        // Normalize to between -1.0 and 1.0, my PCM was signed 16bit
        data[i] = pcm_chunks[i] / 32768;
    }
    node.buffer = buffer;
    node.loop = false;
    node.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    node.start(0);
};
```

One disadvantage I found is the doing it over the network makes the sound lagged even though it works perfect when setting it on localhost.

Clearly, you are more than welcome to comment and suggest another ideas.

---

Edit:

I actually found a way better solution using vlc (or cvlc). It appears that vlc can take a rtp stream and restream it with several manipulations.

```
cvlc rtp://source_ip:source_port --sout '#transcode{acodec=mp3}:standard{access=http,mux=mp3,dst=dest_ip:dest_port}'
```

When launching that process, the client can be the most simple HTML5 audio tag:

```
<audio controls autoplay>
    <source src="http://dest_ip:dest_port" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

Comment: Any practical use-cases of this solution, where we can use this technology.

Comment: could you provide a link for solution 2 using clvc?

Comment: What do you mean by link? A git repository?